# Xamarin.Forms platform specific code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Good day readers,
i'm trying to use a method that is ment for android how do i cast the ContentPage to an Activity of android in PCL is it even possible ?

Tried with directives but its also not working

```
 public static void AddEvent(GSDEvents ev, Activity ac)
        {
            // Id++;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default, Locale.Default);
            ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, Id);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, ev.Title);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, ev.Description);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(ev.Year, ev.Month, ev.Day, ev.Hour, ev.Minute));
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(ev.Year, ev.Month, ev.Day, ev.Hour, ev.Minute));
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllDay, ev.AllDay ? "1" : "0");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, ev.HasAlarm ? "1" : "0");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "GMT+1:00");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "GMT+1:00");

            var uriCalendar = ac.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);

            ContentValues remindervalues = new ContentValues();
            remindervalues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Minutes, ev.ReminderMinute);
            remindervalues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.EventId, Id);
            remindervalues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method, (int)Android.Provider.RemindersMethod.Alert);

            var uriCalendarReminder = ac.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.ContentUri, remindervalues);

        }
```

in my contentpage

```
#if __ANDROID__

            GSDEvents ev = new GSDEvents();
            ev.Title = "Test Event";
            ev.Description = "Dit is nog een test van de beschrijving";
            GSDEvents.AddEvent(ev, __THEPROBLEM HOW CAN I GET THE ACTIVITY);    
#endif
```

does someone know how achieve this i'm working in PCL
Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Kind Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Why would you want to cast it to an `Activity`? The idea is that you have `Pages` which are optimised for cross-platform use. If you still need this look at the `Device.OnPlatform` method. Otherwise, please provide a little more background so we can provide you with a useful answer.

Comment: Will do will edit this post

Comment: I still don't really get what you are trying to do. But from what you are posting it looks like you should not want to do it this way. Your best bet would be to look at the `DependencyService`, which I describe on my blog here; http://l.verslu.is/1JbkZ9Q. Also have a look at the XLabs Calendar control if you need a cross-platform calendar https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Calendar-Control

Comment: The one from Xlabs is not building for me it will give me a build error on NativeRender even with the same usings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one activity. Main you find it in your Droid app. If you need something specifically up in the activity code it there and initiate it from withen your Xamarin forms Page with an event. Pages don't really correlate to Activities at least not in the way your thinking.

Xamarin Forms is Cross Platform by design thus if you couldn't do it on IOS, WP and Droid you cant do it inside Forms. Since obviously theres no Activities on the other 2 platforms Forms has no concept of an activity withen the PCL.

Im not familiar enough with what a GSDEvent is to help further. But to do what you want your going to have to put an event on your ContentPage. Assign the Code to the event from the Activity in Your Droid Project and fire it inside your PCL when you want it to function.

Alternately you could create a Class in your PCL with an event on it Instantiate it in your droid project and assign the event and then put it into an IOC container that you access from the PCL.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with DependencyService Thnx guys :)
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/